# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'type' of undefined. How to fix that

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]I don't understand why this error appears. I am trying to create profile feature that will get data with axios and will show it by userid. I tried a lot of things and also i did the same thing with other component and everything worked

**ProfileContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Profile from './Profile';
import setUserProfile from '../../redux/profile-reducer'
import * as axios from 'axios';

class ProfileContainer extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
axios.get(`https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/profile/2`).then(response => {
            this.props.setUserProfile(response.data);  
        });
    };

render() {
        return (
        <Profile {...this.props} profile={this.props.profile} />
        ) 
    }
    }
    

let mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        profile: state.profilePage.profile
    });    

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{setUserProfile})(ProfileContainer);
```

**profile-reducer.js**

```
const ADD_POST = 'ADD-POST'
const UPDATE_NEW_POST_TEXT = 'UPDATE-NEW-POST-TEXT'
const SET_USER_PROFILE = 'SET_USER_PROFILE';

let initialState = {
  posts: [
    { id: 1, message: 'How are you bro?)', likesCount: 21312 },
    { id: 2, message: 'Have you ever been to Georgia?', likesCount: 31312312 },
  ],
  newPostText: 'q',
  profile: null
};

const profileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POST: 
      let newPost = {
        id: 124331,
        message: state.newPostText,
        likesCount: 0
      }
      return { ...state, posts: [...state.posts, newPost], newPostText: '' }
    case UPDATE_NEW_POST_TEXT: 
      return { ...state, newPostText: action.newText };
    case SET_USER_PROFILE: 
      return { ...state, profile: action.profile };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const addPostActionCreator = () => ({ type: ADD_POST });

export const updateNewPostTextActionCreator = (text) => ({ type: UPDATE_NEW_POST_TEXT, newText: text });

export const setUserProfile = (profile) => ({ type: SET_USER_PROFILE, profile });

export default profileReducer;
```

Comment: state.profilePage is undefined. Unless you have some more code you are not showing, your are not setting profilePage anywhere on the code above so it will always be undefined.

Comment: what exactly i should show here? I mean that i did the same thing in the UsersContainer and usersReducer and everything worked

Comment: `let mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ profile: state.profilePage.profile });`
you don't have profilePage in your state - your state has:
posts, newPostText, profile.
It will always be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You must use async/await in your code.
take a look at this article: https://medium.com/@matt.readout/using-javascripts-async-await-syntax-to-fetch-data-in-a-react-app-878b930cdc6f

you will find the same code there.